# Create a custom button for Price book

Tags: lightning

I am trying to create a custom button in the Price Book layout. The problem is that when i go to Object Manager->Price book i cannot see the menu "Buttons, Links, and Actions" for Price Book, but for other objects i can see it and add custom buttons. Is there anything special about the Price book object and custom buttons? Is it a limitation of Salesforce?

I was not able to find any official documentation about that.

See the screenshot for the different menu : [image]

Comment: This is not possible in standard functionality.
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000iWO1QAM

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, it's not possible to have custom buttons for Pricebooks.
There's an Idea for that: [Idea (click)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CSSqQAO)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, PriceBook object does not allow any custom button on it. It is a Limitation in Salesforce. As a workaround, You can create custom lightning component or visualforce pages and place it directly on page layout. It will not appear as button or action but it will give you the flexibility to achieve your functionality.

Reference:- [Allow custom buttons on Pricebooks](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CSSqQAO)